# Dealing with missing timesteps in RNNs when the time dimension matters

Tags: missing-data, recurrent-neural-network

One way I've found to deal with missing timesteps for an RNN is to process the instances with a batch size = 1. However, in my case, the time dimension matters. To understand what I mean, here's a simple example:

Let's say I have two instances in my dataset (to examine the side effects of a drug with time): 1- data from patient 1 for days 3 and 4 after taking the drug 2- data from patient 2 for days 1 and 10 after taking the drug

Although for both patients I have data for two timesteps (where 1 timestep = 1 day), the spacing of the days and their location on the time axis is very important. My hunch is that if I process this data with batch_size = 1 to solve the problem of missing timesteps, the RNN will treat these two instances similarly (i.e it'll conflate day 1 with day 3 and day 2 with day 10), when they are in fact very different. Is this correct? Does this mean I'll have to resort to some other method to process this data? Additionally, would padding work and be a good alternative in my case?